# PredicateBuilder issue with ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack OrmLite PredicateBuilder to build a WHERE statement dynamically:

```
   var q = PredicateBuilder.True<ItemList>();

   if (!filter.Keyword.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
   {
         q = q.And(i => i.Brand.Contains(filter.Keyword) ||      i.ItemDescription.Contains(filter.Keyword) || i.Serial.Contains(filter.Keyword));
   }

   if (!filter.ItemStatus.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
   {
         q=q.And(i => i.ItemStatus == filter.ItemStatus);
   }

   var count = await Db.CountAsync(Db.From<ItemList>().Where(q));
```

If none of the if statements conditions are met, I get an error on executing the query:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'ORDER'

The reason is that the query that is generated is:

> Select [list of fields] from ItemList WHERE True

**UPDATE: I am using the SQL Server 2012 Dialect provider.**

And this is obviously not valid, is this expected behaviour?

I can use a boolean to check if any condition is being met and then apply the predicate expression, but it is cumbersome.

I was expecting if using only the predicate without any added clause I would get:

> WHERE True=True

Or something equivalent.

Is this the correct way of using the PredicateBuilder?

Comment: Which DialectProvider (eg what type of DB are you connecting to) are you using where you're having this problem?

Comment: Sorry forgot about that....updated the question

Comment: Same problem here, pinging @mythz